# Burning DVDs to disk - what audio codec should I pick?

Tags: audio, dvd, codec, dvd-burning

I finally got around to burning all the DVDs to files, so that I can get rid of all the plastic media once and for all.  Most DVDs have several audio codecs available (2 channel stereo or 5.1 Dolby).  I have a standard HDTV and do not have a Dolby 5.1 setup.

Should I burn the DVDs with the 2 channel stereo audio codec, given the situation?  Will the audio quality be worse?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There will be no quality loss with your current setup, but IMO you should keep the 5.1 - disk space is cheap and your player will downmix it, and you can take advantage of it if you ever do get 5.1-channel audio hardware.

Answer (score 2):

If you're not truly an audio buff, stick to the 2 channels. It is more than enough for your movie nights and family entertainment. There isn't really a noticeable difference.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if it is, you will not notice the difference, as you do not have the equipment required to hear the difference.